# Unable to apply "Top-Down Memoization" approach to Subset Sum using 2d array cache

Tags: java

I am trying to implement Top-Down Memoization approach to Subset-Sum problem using 2d array as cache. Below is the code which i  have tried so far. But I am not getting expected result from code.

```
public static void main(String []args){
       int set[] = {3, 34, 4, 12, 5, 2};
          int sum = 9;
          int n = set.length;
          if (isSubsetSum(set, n, sum) == true)
             System.out.println("Found a subset with given sum");
          else
             System.out.println("No subset with given sum");
     }

      static boolean isSubsetSum(int set[], int n, int sum){

         int[][] dp = new int[n][sum+1];

          for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
              for(int j = 0 ; j < sum ; j++)
                dp[i][j] = -1;



         for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){
             dp[i][0] = 1;
         }

        return isSubsetSum1(set,n-1,sum,dp);
      }


      static boolean isSubsetSum1(int set[], int n, int sum,int[][] dp)
    {
       // Base Cases
       if (sum == 0)
         return true;
       if (n == 0 && sum != 0)
         return false;


       if(dp[n][sum] == -1){

           dp[n][sum] = isSubsetSum1(set, n-1, sum,dp) ? 1 : 0;

           if(sum > set[n-1]){
               boolean result  = isSubsetSum1(set, n-1, sum,dp) || 
                                   isSubsetSum1(set, n-1, sum-set[n-1],dp);
                dp[n][sum] = result ? 1 : 0;                

           }

       }


       return dp[n][sum] == 1 ? true : false;                               

    }
```

Please help me to find logical bug in code.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: I have defined intput in main() method. Numbers list 3, 34, 4, 12, 5, 2 and does list have numbers having sum 9

Comment: Expected result is "Found a subset with given sum". Because list 3, 34, 4, 12, 5, 2 have two number 5 & 4 to form sum 9

Comment: When you call the method `isSubsetSum1(set, n - 1, sum, dp)` your `n` is `6` and `sum` is `9`. Your `dp[5][9]` is `0`. I Think that your `for (int j = 0; j < sum; j++)` is wrong. You need to add `j <= sum`. This is your first error.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a dynamic programming solution which requires no recursion. Basically you have to build a matrix (2d array cache) with look-backs according to some contract.

I have tried to solve the problem with Kotlin finding out how many subset combinations you have given an integer array. It produces in the case of `2 3 4 5 12 34` a matrix which tells you how many combinations you have per expected number. The expected number is in the example below the left most column:

```
   2 3 4 5 1234
0  1 1 1 1 1 1 
1  0 0 0 0 0 0 
2  1 1 1 1 1 1 
3  0 1 1 1 1 1 
4  0 0 1 1 1 1 
5  0 1 1 2 2 **2** 
6  0 0 1 1 1 1 
7  0 0 1 2 2 2 
8  0 0 0 1 1 **1** 
9  0 0 1 2 2 **2**
```

If you read this table it tells you that for sum with 5 given the full array (`2 3 4 5 12 34`) you have 2 subsets, for 8 you have only one and for 9 two, etc. These examples are highlighted above.

You could build this array with this Kotlin code:

```
fun subsetTable(coinsA: IntArray, total: Int): Array<IntArray> {
    val coins = coinsA.sorted()
    val size = coins.size
    val table = Array(total + 1, { IntArray(size) })
    (0 until size).forEach { table[0][it] = 1 }
    (1..total).forEach { row ->
        (0 until coins.size).forEach { col ->
            if (col == 0) {
                table[row][col] = if (row == coins[0]) 1 else 0
            } else {
                val x = if (row - coins[col] >= 0) table[row - coins[col]][col - 1] else 0
                val y = if (col >= 1) table[row][col - 1] else 0
                table[row][col] = x + y
            }
        }
    }
    return table
}
```

Disclaimer: I have not tested the code extensively, so there might be some problems with it.

If you are interested I can convert this code to Java.